# function returns an empty vector

Tags: c++, recursion

I am trying to return a vector of strings from a function, but every time I do so I get an empty vector.However when I try to print the vector in the function itself it's not empty but when I try to print the returned vector I am getting nothing printed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
vector<string> permute(string S, string chosen){
    vector<string> permutated_strings;
    if(S.empty())
        permutated_strings.push_back(chosen);
    else{
         for(int i=0;i<S.length();i++){
            char c = S[i];
            chosen += c;

            S.erase(i,1);
            permute(S,chosen);

            //backtrack
            chosen.erase(chosen.length()-1,1);
            S.insert(i,1,c);
        }
    } 
    return permutated_strings;
}

int main() {
    //code
    int test;
    cin >> test;
    while(test)
    {
        string S;
        cin >> S;
        vector<string> vec;
        vector<string> ::iterator i;
        vec = permute(S,"");
        for(i=vec.begin();i!=vec.end();i++)
            cout<<*i<<" ";
        cout << "\n";
        test--;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I am printing the vector in the permute function I am getting the right result but when I am printing the vector in main function it is empty. Can somebody please point me out the mistake I am doing.

Comment: `permute(S, chosen);` you don't save the result of that recursive call anywhere. It is just discarded.

Comment: You only return the result of the first entry into `permute`. When you recursively call `permute` you don't do anything with the return value.

Comment: You should add result of recursive call of `permute` to `permutated_strings`.

Comment: The most important thing to know about recursive functions is that they work exactly like non-recursive functions.

Comment: [`std::next_permutation`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation) might help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to save result of recursive call of `permute` method.

```
auto result = permute(S,chosen);
permutated_strings.insert(permutated_strings.end(), result.begin(), result.end());
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. It was really helpful . @BartekPL

Answer (score -1):

I got the mistake that I was doing. I really hate answering my own questions but it may help someone like me in the future.

I have changed -

```
vector<string> permutated_strings;
```

to

```
static vector<string> permutated_strings;
```

in the permute function so that previous returns from the recursive calls are not lost. By doing so I am getting the desired result.

Thanks everyone for pointing me to the mistake that I was doing.

> > EDIT

As suggested by @M.M that this solution may cause problem in future. And I have realized that if I give "test" value as 2 the final value in the permutated_strings will be from test=1 + test =2 which is not which I wanted. So this solution is not the perfect one. Instead I am accepting solution from @BartekPL.

Comment: Although this might seem to work for now, there are a few problems that might bite you. For example if you want to call `permute` again later on in the program then there will be state left around from the previous call. And it won't work at all if you have multiple threads.   The solution suggested by BartekPL is much cleaner.